# Horizontal Scrolling not working with RecylerView inside ViewPager2 Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, horizontal-scrolling, android-viewpager2

I am trying to implement the Horizontal RecyclerView inside the ViewPager2, but its not working.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp">
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvMusicList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:listitem="@layout/items_music"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>
...
```

**My Kotlin Code is below**

```
 rvBottomMenu.apply {
                layoutManager =
                    LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false)
                adapter = bottomMenuAdapter
                setHasFixedSize(true)
            }
```

I tried the below link solution, but not worked:
[text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59892000/problem-with-horizontal-recyclerview-in-android)

Comment: Please provide more information about current solution and what exactly does not work.

Comment: I am using inside viewpager, where while scrolling horizontally, it get swipe to another page instead of scrolling.

Comment: Please add this information to the question. It can be helpful to other people when you find the answer,

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this! inside view Pager adapter while setting recycler view adapter set LinearLayoutManger as horizontal

```
 recylcerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false));
```

Comment: I have already used this, even it’s not working. Actually I am using inside viewpager, where while scrolling horizontally, it get swipe to another page instead og scrolling.